# Change "App Icon Source" in "Target > General" (not Info.plist) using (Fastlane-)script

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I just started using Fastlane for automatic deployment of our iOS apps. We have a few white labels (same app, different styling, content, icons, etc.).

Using Fastlane I'm able to change almost all settings before starting the build (version & build number, Launch Screen File, etc.).

Where I'm struggling is the App Icon Source. We use image sets (one `AppIcon-NAME.appiconset` per app). See below image for reference where it's set:
[image]

How would I go about changing this property using Fastlane, any other custom script or in the build phase? This seems to be changes in `xcodeproj.pbxproj` and not `Info.plist`, which makes it significantly harder to find.

Thanks.

Comment: I would try to find out what file and location exactly gets modified when you change something in the UI you posted above. That should make it easier to find the appropriate action of fastlane (or help to decide if to use the [`xcodeproj`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) ruby library in the `Fastfile` lane directly if no matching action exists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `gym` to build the app, right?

You could use the `xcargs` parameter and pass the path to your `.appiconset` file using the `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME` key.

```
gym(
  xcargs: "ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME=./path/to/your/icon/file"
)
```

You can find the doc for `gym` [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/), unfortunately there isn't official documentation for the `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME` build setting.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I made a custom action named update_appicon.rb.

```
# coding: utf-8
module Fastlane
  module Actions
    class UpdateAppicon < Action
      def self.run(params)
        require 'plist'
        require 'xcodeproj'

        info_plist_key = 'INFOPLIST_FILE'
        appicon_name = 'ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME'

        # Load .xcodeproj
        project_path = params[:xcodeproj]
        project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)

        # Fetch the build configuration objects
        configs = project.objects.select { |obj| obj.isa == 'XCBuildConfiguration'}
        UI.user_error!("Not found XCBuildConfiguration from xcodeproj") unless configs.count > 0

        configs = configs.select { |obj| obj.build_settings[info_plist_key] == params[:plist_path] }
        UI.user_error!("Xcodeproj doesn't have configuration with info plist #{params[:plist_path]}.") unless configs.count > 0

        # For each of the build configurations, set app identifier
        configs.each do |c|
          c.build_settings[appicon_name] = params[:appicon_name]
        end

        # Write changes to the file
        project.save

        UI.success("Updated #{params[:xcodeproj]} .")
      end

      #####################################################
      # @!group Documentation
      #####################################################

      def self.is_supported?(platform)
        [:ios].include?(platform)
      end

      def self.description
        "Update the project's bundle identifier"
      end

      def self.details
        "Update an app identifier by either setting `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME`."
      end

      def self.available_options
        [
          FastlaneCore::ConfigItem.new(key: :xcodeproj,
                                       env_name: "FL_UPDATE_APPICON_PROJECT_PATH",
                                       description: "Path to your Xcode project",
                                       default_value: Dir['*.xcodeproj'].first,
                                       verify_block: proc do |value|
                                         UI.user_error!("Please pass the path to the project, not the workspace") unless value.end_with?(".xcodeproj")
                                         UI.user_error!("Could not find Xcode project") unless File.exist?(value)
                                       end),
          FastlaneCore::ConfigItem.new(key: :plist_path,
                                       env_name: "FL_UPDATE_APPICON_PLIST_PATH",
                                       description: "Path to info plist, relative to your Xcode project",
                                       verify_block: proc do |value|
                                         UI.user_error!("Invalid plist file") unless value[-6..-1].casecmp(".plist").zero?
                                       end),
          FastlaneCore::ConfigItem.new(key: :appicon_name,
                                       env_name: 'FL_APPICON_ID',
                                       description: 'appicon name')
        ]
      end

      def self.authors
        ['ruman']
      end

      def self.category
        :project
      end
    end
  end
```

And it applied on fastfile

```
update_appicon(
    xcodeproj: "YourProjectName.xcodeproj",
    plist_path: "Info.plist",
    appicon_name: "AppIcon#{options[:app_icon]}"
)
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to rebuild the app after that?

Comment: Yes. After this lane, you should build again. For me, I build with gym action after this lane.

Comment: This is perfect! No Idea about ruby and what this code means but I will sure learn after this.